# navigation in windowedapplication flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop air application in flex. I have 2 mxml *(one mxml is windowedapplication and another one in mxml group)*. I want to navigate from one mxml file (`login.mxml`) to another (`nextpage.mxml`).

How can I acheive this?

login.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>`enter code here`
<![CDATA[
public function onLogin()
{
// What code should i use to navigate to another mxml page i.e nextpage.mxml
}
]]>
</fx:Script><s:Button id="btn" name="Login" click="onLogin()"/</s:WindowedApplication>
```

nextpage.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="Login Success/></s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to implement the main application as a coordinator of the application's state.

In this case you can use the ViewStack component, which has Login and NextPage components as children. The components communicate with the application by means of events. Depending on the current event the state is changed.

//Main app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:fld01="com.fld01.*">

<mx:ViewStack id="vsMain">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="ncLogin">
        <fld01:Login id="grLogin" evtLogin="{vsMain.selectedChild = ncNextPage}"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>

    <s:NavigatorContent id="ncNextPage">
        <fld01:Nextpage id="grNextPage" evtLogout="{vsMain.selectedChild = ncLogin}"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

//Login

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">

<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="evtLogin", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function onLogin():void
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("evtLogin"));  
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="btn" x="40" y="50" label="Login" click="onLogin()"/>
</s:Group>
```

//NextPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
     width="400" height="300">

<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="evtLogout", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function onLogout():void
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event("evtLogout")); 
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label x="40" y="50" text="Login Success"/>

<s:Button id="btn" x="40" y="80" label="Logout" click="onLogout()"/>

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Thank u so much it worked out for me! A small change is that instead of giving 'fld01:Login' i used 'local:Login' then only it worked for me.